# iframe content is displaying outside the iframe on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, mobile-safari

Here is a fiddle (jsfiddle.net/salman/RQBra/show/) that demonstrates the problem I am facing. The iframes appear as expected in all browsers (including Safari 5 for Windows). But when I viewed the page on two iOS devices (iPad and iPhone) the content of iframe overflowed and covered the entire area on the right hand side of the iframe. Here is a screenshot of a page that uses similar iframes:

[image: iframe overflowing on x-direction on iOS]

How can I workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, try to wrap the iframes in divs, but not constraining the iframe's width and height by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it in a div, but on the iPhone it won't be scrollable without some javascript. I've made a fiddle that shows how you can fix the size of the iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/RQBra/29/

basically, you wrap your iframe in a wrapper and give it some css:

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
width:400px;
height:400px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for your specific case is to replace the  `<iframe>` by an `<embed>` element.

```
<embed src="..." type="text/html" width="400" height="400"></embed>
```

It will have the desired effect on Safari Mobile and clip the content to the specified `width` and `height` dimensions instead of auto-sizing it. Hoewever, embed is not specifically designed for HTML content and unwanted effects may result when dealing with scrolling, `contentWindow` and different environments (it is not necessarily rendered natively), so test the case before using it in production.

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/embed):

> The  element represents an integration point for an external
>   (typically non-HTML) application or interactive content.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing inside Iframe there is an HTML file, so in HTML wrap the content in wrapper div

```
#wrapper {
position: relative;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

it's size will be relative to html body, than the viewportSizes may be as you wish
the second row is handling flickering on Iframe click, happens in ios'...