# Div inside IFrame is not taking the given height

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, iframe

We are using an IFrame which works fine when viewed in all browsers.However when viewed in **IPad** the **content of div inside IFrame Overflows below**.
Refering to the link [IFrame in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528760/iframe-content-is-displaying-outside-the-iframe-on-ios), The solution given over here shown [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQBra/29/) gives the adds a wrapper

```
 #wrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

to parent div of IFrame. But the div inside IFrame still Overflow below

The image below shows scroll bar coming inside div of iframe when viewed in the browsers.
[image: Working fine in system Browser]

Viewed in IPad
[image: Problem in ipad]

Any Suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have something like this in your header: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">` - could be causing it to resize

Comment: No its not there in header.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing inside Iframe there is an HTML file, so in HTML wrap the content in wrapper div

```css
#wrapper {
position: relative;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

it's size will be relative to html body, than the viewportSizes may be as you wish the second row is handling flickering on Iframe click, happens in ios'...

Answer (score -1):

```
you can use this;
<div> tag should be set as.
<div style="overflow:hidden"></div>
```